# MS Word Merge: How to exclude non-numeric characters in an 'amount' merge field

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

**ENVIRONMENT**

I need to do a weekly mail merge to create letter receipts for donations. The database program we are using produces an Excel file  (xls) that is then merged into a Word document (2010) to print the receipts. There will be 3 - 6 thousand receipts printed receipts per run. We receive donations in many different currencies.

**PROBLEM**

The database program exports the currency amount with the Currency Symbol and with no decimal point. e.g.:
$5000  ($50 USD)
or 
E500000   (5000.00 Euro)
or
CHF1000    (10 Swiss Franks)

(I do not know why the developers decided to do this! But in general the program is quite good.)

With a simple formula in the merge field I was able to take off the USD and EURO symbol, and then divide the amount by 100.

```
{ = { MERGEFIELD currency_amount \# 0.00}  / 100 \# #,0.00}
```

However this formula gives me a problem for currency like CHF. I am getting this error:  `!Undefiend Bookmark, CHF1000`

---

I have tried to modify the formula and searched online but no success so far.

Does anybody have a solution or an idea how to solve it? If possible I do not want to edit the original excel file  (e.g. run a macro, search & replace etc).

Also the user that will execute the merges is not that computer savvy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I hope someone has a neat solution, but in my view, every solution to this problem is likely to introduce complication that would be avoided if you could change the extraction software - either split the currency string and amount into two columns or at the very least, introduce a space between the "CHF" and the number.

U think you can do this using a large set of field codes, but it will be simpler if only "CHF" causes the problem. Another way that does not require editing of the data source is given below, but that is only likely to be useful in some cases.

I don't think you can do this using a *simple* set of field codes, because although you can write code that will detect whether or not Word will treat the amount as a number or not, there is still a problem when you discover that it is not a number.

You can use the following set of fields to determine whether Word is going to treat the value as a number or not:

```
{ SET tmp { MERGEFIELD currency_amount } }{ IF { tmp } = { =tmp } "it's a number" "it's not a number" }
```

That should work OK and raise no errors at merge time. The case where it won't work as hoped is where, for example, you have a value CHF1000 and you actually do have a bookmark called "CHF1000".

In the case where Word thinks it's a number, you can then use { =tmp #0 } to get the number and do what you need with it.

In the case where it isn't, you then have to consider how you can get the numeric part out of the field.

You can't use the { = } in any useful way. (It is sometimes possible to use arithmetic "tricks" to get stuff out of the number, but I don't think it is possible in this case).

You can't use indirection in any useful way (e.g. where you use something like

```
{ DOCVARIABLE { REF tmp } }
```

to access a variable called CHF1000 with a value of 1000. To do that you would need one such variable for every possible amount. Actually, if you could only get amounts up to, say, CHF9999 it might be workable.

So I think you have to use "brute force" to extract the digits one by one. Again, if it's just for CHF and the numbers are always in the same format (CHF1, CHF2,..,CHF1000 etc.) and you know the maximum number of digits, you could do that with a whole bunch of IF fields like this:

```
{ IF tmp = "CHF0*" { SET tmp2 "0" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF1*" { SET tmp2 "1" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF2*" { SET tmp2 "2" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF3*" { SET tmp2 "3" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF4*" { SET tmp2 "4" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF5*" { SET tmp2 "5" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF6*" { SET tmp2 "6" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF7*" { SET tmp2 "7" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF8*" { SET tmp2 "0" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF9*" { SET tmp2 "9" }
}{ SET tmp1 { tmp2 }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF?0*" { SET tmp2 "{ tmp1 }0" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF?1*" { SET tmp2 "{ tmp1 }1" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF?2*" { SET tmp2 "{ tmp1 }2" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF?3*" { SET tmp2 "{ tmp1 }3" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF?4*" { SET tmp2 "{ tmp1 }4" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF?5*" { SET tmp2 "{ tmp1 }5" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF?6*" { SET tmp2 "{ tmp1 }6" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF?7*" { SET tmp2 "{ tmp1 }7" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF?8*" { SET tmp2 "{ tmp1 }8" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF?9*" { SET tmp2 "{ tmp1 }9" }
}{ SET tmp1 { tmp2 }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF??0*" { SET tmp2 "{ tmp1 }0" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF??1*" { SET tmp2 "{ tmp1 }1" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF??2*" { SET tmp2 "{ tmp1 }2" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF??3*" { SET tmp2 "{ tmp1 }3" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF??4*" { SET tmp2 "{ tmp1 }4" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF??5*" { SET tmp2 "{ tmp1 }5" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF??6*" { SET tmp2 "{ tmp1 }6" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF??7*" { SET tmp2 "{ tmp1 }7" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF??8*" { SET tmp2 "{ tmp1 }8" }
}{ IF tmp = "CHF??9*" { SET tmp2 "{ tmp1 }9" }
}{ SET tmp1 { tmp2 }
}
```

and repeat that lot for each digit you could possibly have, icnreasing the number of "?" characters by one each time. Then use { =tmp1 #0 } to get the value.

The other way you could consider with an Excel data source is to write VBA that uses Jet SQL to modify the data (i.e., it won't modify the 'master data'). If there is only one user, you are defining all the mail merge main documents, and you can replicate their environment, in theory you only have to run the VBA once - each time they re-open their Mail Merge Main Document the same SQL will be executed. In practice it's rarely so simple. If you only have to deal with 'CHF' you could use code along the following lines:

```
Sub SetupDataSource()
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
  Name:="c:\a\yourdatasource.xlsx", _
  sqlstatement:="SELECT t.*, iif(ucase(left(t.currency_amount,3))='CHF',mid(t.currency_amount,4),t.currency_amount) AS new_amount FROM [Sheet1$] t"
End Sub
```

If you have to detect more "anomalies" or you need to extract from several currency fields, things can be harder because

- Not all the string handling functions in VBA are available in Jet
  when connecting via OLE DB in this way
- Word limits the SQL to 511 characters (possibly 255 in some cases).
  It's not actually a lot.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I will attempt the SQL method first and post back with results but that seems the simplest in my environment.